# When postgreSQL Copy command execute

Tags: postgresql, windows

After creating a csv file in the program because a large amount of data needs to be inserted
I am trying to insert into a table using the postgreSQL copy command.

However, if I put the CSV file in the C drive of the Windows server where the DB is installed and test it, INSERT works well.
If you place a CSV file in the Z drive opened as a shared folder and test it, the following error occurs.

ERROR: Failed to open file "Z:\TEST_ZZ.csv" in diary mode: No such file or directory
Hint: The COPY FROM command is processed by the PostgreSQL server process by reading a file. To read and process a file on the client side, use psql's \copy built-in command.

I opened all the folder and file permissions, what could be the problem?
If you know postgreSQL well, I would appreciate it if you could reply!

Answer (score 0):

From [a question on DBA Stackexchange](https://dba.stackexchange.com/a/154826/176905):

> `COPY` runs as the PostgreSQL server, which usually runs as `NETWORKSERVICE` on Windows. This is a local service account that does not have access to your user account's network login credentials for shared drives.